Should I use a hardware RAID controller with my NVMe SSDs for a Hyper-V server hosting production VMs?
I want to set up a Hyper-V server to run four production VMs: a Linux database server (HANA), a Windows Terminal Server, and a couple of Windows 10 VMs.
Up until now, I’ve always used SATA SSDs in a hardware RAID setup with a RAID controller and BBU. For better performance on my database server, I’m considering switching to NVMe SSDs instead of SATA SSDs. My main reason for considering RAID is to ensure that my servers stay online if one of the disks fails. I have daily backups, but restoring from them would take time and could result in data loss between the last backup and the failure. I want to avoid both downtime and data loss if possible.
What would you recommend in this scenario? I’m open to any suggestions.
So far, I’ve found that hardware RAID controllers for NVMe drives are rare, and most of them have lower performance, which defeats the purpose of using NVMe drives. There is the option of Intel vROC, but I’m concerned about its reliability and support, as Intel announced plans to discontinue it. Any guidance here would be appreciated.
Additionally, what RAID level would be best in this case? RAID 1, 5, 6, or 10? Do you have suggestions on the number of virtual LUNs for hosting the VHDX files of the production VMs?
I’ve also seen suggestions for ZFS, but I haven’t been able to fully understand or apply it in this context.

There are hardware RAID controllers that support NVMe storage and export PCIe Virtual Functions so they can be passed to VMs without the overhead of hypervisor calls. That could be worth it.

@SimonRichter Would you mind sharing a recommendation suitable for 3.84TB x 4 PM9A3 SSDs, which would not be a bottleneck for the performance?

I don't have enough of a market overview to make good recommendations -- but there are only a handful players in this market, and all of them have application engineers who actually know the product and can make firm statements on performance.

Lots of questions, let me break ‘em down for you one by one.

Yeah, "classic" hardware RAID controllers for NVMe drives are pretty rare, mostly ‘cause they kill performance, and people aren’t into that. See, they basically "multiplex" the PCIe lanes from the NVMe drives onto the mobo. So, if you’ve got an x16 PCIe slot with a RAID controller attached to it, you can only get four x4 PCIe NVMe drives running at their full speed. Any more than that and the bandwidth starts choking, and you’re stuck with poor performance. Leaving money on the table ain't good!

What you can do is go with a GPU-based RAID controller. This setup uses the mobo’s PCIe slots for the NVMe drives (so no bandwidth loss unless you run outta PCIe lanes from the CPU, which is unlikely). It offloads all the parity number-crunching to the GPU, so your CPU can actually do what it’s supposed to which is running your production VMs. A good example is GRAID, check it out here:
https://www.graidtech.com/supremeraid-virtualization-platforms/

RAID won’t save you if your PSU dies or your CPU fries. What you really need is to bring in a second server and set up a Hyper-V HA cluster. You’ll want to replicate your storage between the two nodes, and for the highest-performance setup that also works with hardware RAIDs (Incl. GRAID), StarWind Virtual SAN’s the move. It’ll basically “network” RAID1 your local RAID5 or RAID6 NVMe pools for true redundancy. You’ll get zero downtime and zero data loss if something goes wrong hardware-wise. For StarWind vSAN, check this out:

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san
And for setting up Hyper-V clusters, here’s a good guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj863389(v=ws.11)
Windows Server Datacenter comes with this built-in feature called Storage Spaces Direct (S2D), which does both local RAID and inter-node replication, but we usually skip it because it’s a little iffy with stability (especially when paired with ReFS) and doesn’t perform as well.

Intel vROC? Yeah, that’s not great for production. It’s Linux MDRAID-based, but Intel added too many private mods, making it super unlikely the community will pick it up if Intel decides to stop supporting it.

(No links for this, it’s all rumors for now, but you can see where it’s headed since 2023. The writing is on the wall for a long time already!)

With NVMe drives, RAID5 works well because rebuilds are fast. If you add internode replication, it’s basically RAID51, which boosts both performance and redundancy. But it’ll cost you, you’ll need to double the number of your NVMe drives. RAID6 and RAID10? Overkill for your needs.

ZFS? Not the best choice for NVMe pools. It’s good for writes because it chops up the data and uses all the drives in the pool, unlike “classic” RAID where only the drives in the “strip” get writes. But reads? Not great. You’ll get the performance of just one NVMe drive for reads, and that’s being generous. Check this link to get a full understanding of ZFS performance:


https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2020/05/zfs-101-understanding-zfs-storage-and-performance/
Cheers, and good luck with your endeavor!
